# Probability that P people will have N distinct birthdays

Tags: probability, statistics, balls-in-bins

This question is rather difficult to describe clearly, so I will begin with an example. Suppose I have a 365 people in a room. The odds are very low that all these people have different birthdays.  In fact, **ignoring leap years and assuming that every birthday is equally likely**, I estimated (using a program) that the most likely scenario is 231 distinct birthdays (with a probability of ~6.69%).

More abstractly, out of P people, what are the odds that there are **exactly** N distinct birthdays amongst them (ignoring leap years and assuming that every birthday is equally likely)? In my above example I used P=365 and I estimated the answer for N=231. I am curious if there is a general solution to the problem which could give an exact answer for all N and P.

For those who are interested, [the program I created](https://gist.github.com/unixpickle/c939744dbdf85126a5cb) tries random combinations of birthdays and counts the number of unused birthdays. With it, I created a table of estimated probabilities for all N for P=365. Here is the most interesting part of the table:

```
242 - 1.1837375%
241 - 1.5966975%
240 - 2.0933325%
239 - 2.6695062%
238 - 3.3059700%
237 - 3.9824950%
236 - 4.6610425%
235 - 5.2969675%
234 - 5.8606362%
233 - 6.2995763%
232 - 6.5841737%
231 - 6.6932175%
230 - 6.6143263%
229 - 6.3563137%
228 - 5.9308837%
227 - 5.3896263%
226 - 4.7588988%
225 - 4.0879863%
224 - 3.4110800%
223 - 2.7697687%
222 - 2.1889950%
221 - 1.6793675%
220 - 1.2546263%
```

Comment: exactly $N$ distinct birthdays or at least $N$?

Comment: **exactly** N distinct birthdays

Comment: Are you ignoring leap year and assuming that all the 365 days in a non-leap year are equally probable? (Both those assumptions are false, of course.)

Comment: Yes, I am making that assumption. I should make that clearer in the question.

Comment: It is not difficult to calculate the expected number of distinct birthdays, which is  $365  \left(1- \left(1-\frac{1}{365}\right)^P\right)$, and when $P=365$ this is about $230.908$ so your use of the mode is close.  For large $P$ the approximation $365\left(1-\exp({-P/365})\right)$ is not too bad and when $P=365$ this is about $230.724$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are $\binom{365}{N}$ ways to select the $N$ birthdays. Then there are $P \brace N$ ways to select select which of the birthdays each person will have so that every of the selected birthdays is indeed the birthday of at least one person.

All in all there are $\binom{365}{N}{P \brace N}N!$ outcomes that give exactly $N$ distinct birthdays.

Hence the probability is:

$$\dfrac{\binom{365}{N}{P \brace N}N!}{365^P}$$

---

Here $\binom{n}{k}$ is the binomial coefficient and $n\brace k$ is the stirling number of the second kind.

Comment: Why is {PN} the value you say it is?

Comment: There was a mistake. See here for an explanation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way

Answer (score 1):

There should be an $N!$ in your numerator, I believe; otherwise, this will not sum to 1...

Comment: Correct !!${}{}{}{}$