# what is the probability that n people will have different birthdays?

Tags: probability, factorial

the formula I worked for the probability that no two or more people will share the same birthday. (no leap years)

$$\frac{365!}{365^n (365-n)!}$$

But what is least number of people such that the probability is at least 0.5? whats the way to calculate this without testing 1 by one?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1172678/probability-that-p-people-will-have-n-distinct-birthdays?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

This is a well known problem called the BIRTHDAY PROBLEM.

You can find all the maths here

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem

If you know the probability for $n$ people to have the same birthday, you can immediately fine the probability for $n$ people to have different birthday.